# Visualizing Time Series data with react and django channels

Tags: python, reactjs, django-rest-framework, visualization, django-channels

Visualizing Time Series data with react and django channels

I am developing a time series data visualization application using Django Channels and React. I am using Redis TimeSeries (Redis TS) to store one month's worth of data. However, the size of the data is quite large, and I need to display all the data in the user interface (UI). Due to the large data size, the transmission time over WebSocket and the endpoint is significantly long. I cannot scale down the data since I need to show all of it. What can I do to solve this problem?

I have tried dividing the data into smaller chunks, but the Highcharts library I'm using in React doesn't support it. It only allows adding one point at a time, which requires iterating through the list and causes time and performance loss

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.